# How to find unique number in 2D Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, language-agnostic, unique

I have a 2D array, the index of the outer array represents the StateID and the integers in the inner arrays represent the StoreIDs.

```
StoreStateList = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,3,7,9],[1,8,12],[7,9,12]]
```

I am trying to find a state that has a store that no other state has. e.g. state 3 with StoreID 8.

My current implementation consists of 4 nested loops which appears inefficient. Does anyone know how I can make the function more efficient?

```
function findUniqueStore(StoreRegionList)
 
   for state in range(len(StoreRegionList):
 
      state_count = 0

      for store in StoreStateList[state]:
         // check if the store in the state occurs in any other state
         for state_inner in range(len(StoreRegionList)):
            for store_inner in StoreStateList[state_inner]:
               if store == store_inner:
                  state_count += 1
      
    if state_count == 1:                     
       return state
```

Comment: what is the programming language you're using ? Is it `Python` ?

Comment: Its basic pseudocode, but I plan to implement it in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two python [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to store potential unique elements and visited elements. Inside your two first for loops, check if the current element has already been seen, if not add it to potential unique elements or otherwise remove it from unique elements if it is still there :

```py
def findUniqueStore(StoreRegionList):

   visitedNumbers = set()
   uniqueNumbers = set()

   for state in range(len(StoreRegionList):
      for store in StoreStateList[state]:
         // check if the store in the state occurs in any other state
         if store not in visitedNumbers:
             uniqueNumbers.add(store)
             visitedNumbers.add(store)
         elif store in uniqueNumbers:
             uniqueNumbers.remove(store)
    
    if len(uniqueNumbers)>0:
       return next(iter(uniqueNumbers))
```

This gives a nlog(n) solution where n is the total number of elements, as opposed to n² for yours.

Edit : I did not realise you didn't explicitly asked for a python solution, but the point is you can use sets which are in every language's standard library and usually implemented with balanced binary trees to support insertion, check and deletion of elements in log(n) time.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I needed. However, I need to return the state number, not the store number. I tried to adjust your code using a state variable but could not make it work (yet). Do you have any solution that returns the state? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use a python dictionary (i.e. a hash table) instead of the `uniqueNumbers` set to store the value of the state associated to potential unique numbers (key=store, value=state). Checking for a key in a dictionary is the same syntax as for checking if an element is in a set. In the end return `uniqueNumbers[next(iter(uniqueNumbers))]`.

Comment: _"you can use sets **which are in every language's standard library**"_  Erm...  Really?!

Comment: @CJK Sure *every* might be an overstatement, but it is definitely in *most* programming languages' standard libraries, and as long as you're using something meant to do algorithms and slightly popular the first google result will tell you how to declare sets.

Comment: You've already backtracked on _every_, and added the caveat _slightly popular_, which you're welcome to both of those, and you'd still be selling an egregious falsehood. There's C, Assembly, Fortran, Lisp (and many functional programming languages for that matter), Perl, most shell scripting languages, Awk, AppleScript, XSLT, SQL (though it provides Set operations), PHP, Logo (still popular, especially in schools), Visual Basic (last I recall), ...  Side-related query: are there any languages _not_ meant to do algorithms ?